# What's the name of the City where "Garfield" takes place?

Tags: film-location, garfield

I wonder what's the name of the City where the 2004 Film "Garfield" takes place. It's never said in the Film but it looks like Los Angeles. Also, I recognized the Train Station from the Film as "Union Station" in Los Angeles. Is there a Reason why they changed the Name of that Train Station for the Film?

Answer (score 3):

I don't think the name of the city is mentioned in the film but the [Wikipedia page for Garfield](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Garfield)  indicates that:

> Though this is rarely mentioned in print, Garfield is set in Muncie, Indiana, the home of Jim Davis

So we can reasonably assume that the city/town in the film can also be termed as Muncie, even though the filming locations are in different places.

Comment: In [Garfield Goes Hollywood](https://www.imdb.com/title/tt0166203/), they mention that they're from Muncie, Indiana. It's a safe bet to say that the movie takes place in the same city.